# How can I set baseFontFamily for bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to set base font family in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss file but for some reason rendered HTML is still taking default font type instead of overriding it. Is there any way to change default values of bootstrap variables?

**bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap";

$baseFontFamily: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif  !default;
$baseFontSize: 11px !default;
```

Rendered css:

```
body {
    color: #333333;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two links on whether you want to alter the source:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594098/How-to-customize-Twitter-Bootstrap-to-fit-your-web

or alter the source via your custom css.scss file:

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-customize-twitter-bootstraps-design-in-a-rails-app/

basically you want to put your overrides BEFORE the import of bootstrap.

```
$baseFontFamily: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif  !default;
$baseFontSize: 11px !default;

@import "bootstrap";
```

The Font Family is defined with

```
@import "bootstrap";

@sansFontFamily: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif
@serifFontFamily: Font you want
```

These are LESS variables and should be defined after the import of bootstrap.

Comment: I changed the sequence as you suggested but no luck. It still taking the same default family style.

Comment: Interestingly, anchor color is overriding properly. Look like this is not proper way to change default font style.

Comment: I think the font family is defined through LESS variables.  If you look in the first link halfway down the typography is defined by `@sansFontFamily:`  I've updated the answer with this info.

Comment: The variable names appear to have changed. I added an answer below with what worked for me and is in sync with the latest bootsrap docs

Answer (score 3):

Per the latest bootstrap documentation, the LESS variables that can be overridden are described here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables

Here are a few examples:

```
@body-bg
@text-color
@font-family-sans-serif
```

Since you are using SASS, just replace the @ prefix with a $ prefix. Like below.

```
$body-bg
$text-color
$font-family-sans-serif
```

And override them before importing the bootstrap files.

So to override the base font family,

```
// note: per the bootstrap docs above, $font-family-base inherits 
// from $font-family-sans-serif
$font-family-sans-serif: NewFont !default;

@import "bootstrap";
```

See more information here for bootstrap-sass https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 2):

The point here is you have to specify **right variable names** in **right position**.

- Right variable names: [**bootstrap less variable names**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables). You need to change `@` character to `$` for **sass syntax**.
- Right position: define your custom variables before call `@import "bootstrap";`. If bootstrap has been loaded, your custom variables will never been used, that's the reason why your code doesn't work.

In this situation, your code should be:

***bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss***

```
$font-family-base: Arial, "Helvetica", sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 11px;

@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables names are incorrect. It should be

`$base-font-family:Arial, "Helvetica", sans-serif;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap-sass gem, the correct name for this variables are

`font-family-base` and `font-size-base`

Also, from the [SASS documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html):

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding
>   the !default flag to the end of the value. This means that if the
>   variable has already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but if
>   it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one.

`!default` it's the SASS equivalent of `||=` operator in Ruby.

So, in your case the following will work:

```
$font-family-base: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif
$font-size-base: 11px
```